# Is It Possible To Use An External Database For User Data & Login Credentials With Shopify?

Tags: authentication, salesforce, cross-domain, shopify

Our client has asked us to build a Shopify site that ties into their in-house customer db (with or without using Salesforce). Is this even possible? Does Shopify support any method of cross-site database querying?

The only thing I can think of to accomplish this is to write a webhook on their in-house server with a simple read-only mini DB query API. However, as that I'm not super familiar with Shopify's more obscure capabilities (and having already spent quite some time sifting through their docs and running google searches on the matter with absolutely zero results), I'm not even sure if this is possible.

Are we barking up an impossible tree, or is this something that can actually be accomplished?

Thank you in advance for any help you can give.

Comment: Your question is vague. What do you mean by "Ties into their in-house customer DB"? Working with customers in Shopify is pretty easy with their API, so given that is Internet-enabled securely, the only question is how Internet enabled is this "in-house" system, and then with that out of the way, what actual business logic are your clients asking for.

Comment: @DavidLazar I'm not sure what's so vague about the question. Two perfectly usable answers have already been given. But thanks for your concern.

Comment: Guesses were that you are concerned with login credentials. And so be it, but you never actually asked that. You are just lucky to have received some relatively useful advice is all I am saying. And since the lucky guesses seemed to have answered your question, my comment was just a test to see if you were after anything more substantial, as that was easily possible. Sorry to bother you.

Comment: @DavidLazar Hey, sorry; I know we're not supposed to use comments like this, but I apologize for my response - I've become very ... put off by StackOverflow lately; what with the down-vote mobs and the cocky IQ-flasher responses and comments. It appears I misread your "vibe". So - my due apologies.

Comment: I missed too.. the subject title you chose was pretty clear, just had a hard time matching to the description... I agree. I vowed to quit StackOverflow too as I've helped hundreds and hundreds for little to no positive gain, just snark!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I have understood from your description is you already have an external database with user login details and you want to use the same for authentication in Shopify. If yes, then it is possible with Shopify Multipass feature. This feature is only available for Shopify Plus plans. From the [Shopify Multipass docs](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/plus/multipass)

> Multipass login is for store owners who have a separate website and a
>   Shopify store. It redirects users from the website to the Shopify
>   store and seamlessly logs them in with the same email address they
>   used to sign up for the original website. If no account with that
>   email address exists yet, one is created. There is no need to
>   synchronize any customer databases.

For your particular scenario, you would have to validate user credentials with your external database, generate *multipass url* and redirect.

Answer (score 2):

Yes your requirement is quite possible. But the method i am going to mention is a hack basically. Below are the steps:

1. Create Login page/Account creation page in Shopify
2. When the user does a login/create account you send the information to your server via below methods

   - JSONP request
   - Creating a iframe of your domain and passing the information in the iframe
3. Now, you validate the user credentials at your server
4. After validating you check if the user is present in Shopify. If not you create the user with a password. [API Link](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/customers/customer#create-2019-07)
5. Make sure you save the user password you push into Shopify at your end also.
6. Now when you have completed authentication of the user, return back Shopify username and password
7. Create a hidden form in Shopify liquid file and pass the credentials in the respective fields and submit the form and user should be able to log in with the existing password they have!

Comment: This is a bit more hacky for sure - but it's doable. I'm going to try @Bilal Akbar 's recommendation first, but if that doesn't pull through with our setup, I'll give this one a try. I just try to avoid iframes if at all possible, but there are definitely circumstances where it's not. Thanks

Comment: @CreationTribe .. based on your clients DB CORS, you may directly use AJAX calls to authenticate .. Easier way would be, delay the form submit on Shopify during login for you to auth with your clients DB .. create/login account accordingly and do the same on Shopify's end as well.. If you do it right, you don't need to create an app..

Comment: How you are gonna handle password resets with that setup?

Comment: @Juju you have to handle the password resets in the same way as the user registration mentioned in the above answer. Create a iframe and pass the information.