# Shopify: Login as Customer

Tags: authentication, shopify, admin, shopify-app, storefront

Does anyone know if there a feature or application to allow admin to "log in as customer"?
Basically, the admin can log in as a customer in the storefront with whatever customer.

I'm looking replicate this https://marketplace.magento.com/magefan-module-login-as-customer.html in Shopify.

Comment: Directly you can not do this as in order to login, you need customer password. but there is another tricky way you can do this but not sure you should do or not. But as techie let me discuss here. You can create custom form for customer signup which will request your server via app proxy. where you collect customer detail save in to DB including their password and create new customer via API.Now you can create another module or app which will create sign in form and submit email and password. and then you can Login.

Comment: This has been already answered. Please check the question -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57439319/is-it-possible-to-use-an-external-database-for-user-data-login-credentials-wit/57441484#57441484

Answer (score 0):

Recently (maybe a month or two ago) Magefan released Login As Customer App for Shopify. You can find it here https://apps.shopify.com/login-as-customer.

As it is quite new, in case of any issues with the app I recomment to contact the Magefan team, usualy they reply fast.